# Find missing period and determine whether consecutive before

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on a requirement to find the missing period and then determine whether it was consecutive before the missing period

Following is my sample table structure.

**First step**: In the following sample table look at last 6 months (`2014 7 - 2014 12`). Its missing two months 8 & 11. Take the first instance 8.

**Second step**: Go back 6 months from the first instance missing - (`2014 2- 2014 7`) - see whether they are missing any months. If No (everything is consecutive) - Select/Include this record if Yes (missing some months) - don't select this record.

```
Year   Month   
2014    1
2014    2
2014    3
2014    4
2014    5
2014    6
2014    7
2014    9
2014    10
2014    12
```

I can select last 6 records and partition by row number and see whether its missing any. But I am not sure how to find if its consecutive and also select the missing period.

I am trying to do as much filtration in Transact-SQL so that I can focus on other validations on c#.

Query I created to find first period missing(not complete)

```
SELECT f.TYEAR,f.TMONTH, f.TMONTH+1 AS MISSING FROM #TEMPTABLE AS F
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMPTABLE AS F2 ON f.TMONTH+1 = f2.TMONTH
WHERE f2.TAXPERIOD IS NULL
```

Note: The above example can span b/w two calendar years. 2013 mm - 2014 mm

Comment: Please add any sql query you have tired to achieve this. Also add sqlfiddle

Comment: What version of sql-server are you working in? This will matter significantly for this sort of problem.

Comment: What if nothing is missing in last six months?

Comment: Sql server 2014. If nothing missing in last 6 months then we dont have to proceed to second step. we can ignore this record.

Comment: It's probably easiest to find missing periods by having a separate table of months -- and to check previous 6 you can use LAG() -function

Comment: Go back 6 months from the first instance missing should be - (2014 2- 2014 7)  right?

Comment: And also it should work for scenarios where theres a switch in tax year - Mixed years- Same ex but starts from 2013 some month to 2014 some month

Answer (score 0):

I think below code should work, though I've not tested it properly. But you will get the idea -

```
DECLARE @TmpBaseTable TABLE ([Year] SMALLINT, [Month] TINYINT)
DECLARE @TmpSixMonthTable TABLE (TmpYear SMALLINT, TmpMonth TINYINT)
DECLARE @TmpDate DATE
DECLARE @MissingYear SMALLINT
DECLARE @MissingMonth TINYINT
DECLARE @TmpCount TINYINT


INSERT INTO @TmpBaseTable ([Year], [Month])
SELECT 2014, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 2014, 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, 4

SELECT TOP 1 @TmpDate = CAST(CAST(tmpYear AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(tmpMonth AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Year], [Month]) AS RowID, [Month] AS tmpMonth, [Year] AS tmpYear
    FROM @TmpBaseTable
)
tmp ORDER BY RowID DESC

INSERT INTO @TmpSixMonthTable  (TmpMonth, TmpYear)
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -5, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -5, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -4, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -4, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -3, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -3, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -2, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -2, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -1, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -1, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -0, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -0, @TmpDate))

SELECT TOP 1 @MissingMonth = tmpSix.TmpMonth, @MissingYear = tmpSix.TmpYear FROM @TmpSixMonthTable tmpSix
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TmpBaseTable tmpBase ON tmpSix.TmpMonth = tmpBase.[Month] AND tmpSix.TmpYear = tmpBase.[Year]
WHERE tmpBase.[Year] IS NULL

SET @TmpDate = CAST(CAST(@MissingYear AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@MissingMonth AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)

DELETE FROM @TmpSixMonthTable

INSERT INTO @TmpSixMonthTable  (TmpMonth, TmpYear)
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -6, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -6, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -5, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -5, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -4, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -4, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -3, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -3, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -2, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -2, @TmpDate)) UNION ALL
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, -1, @TmpDate)), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD (MONTH, -1, @TmpDate))


SELECT @TmpCount = COUNT(1) FROM @TmpSixMonthTable tmp1
INNER JOIN @TmpBaseTable tmp2 ON tmp1.TmpMonth = tmp2.[Month] AND tmp1.TmpYear = tmp2.[Year]

IF(@TmpCount = 6)
BEGIN
    SELECT tmp2.[Month], tmp2.[Year] FROM @TmpSixMonthTable tmp1
    INNER JOIN @TmpBaseTable tmp2 ON tmp1.TmpMonth = tmp2.[Month] AND tmp1.TmpYear = tmp2.[Year]
END
```

There can be a smarter way than this :)

Comment: Hi Kartic Thanks for the Reply. I am not sure whether this will handle scenarios where theres a switch in tax year ie 2013 some month to 2014 some month

Comment: ok, I though it is applicable for only one calendar year. I'll update my query

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that in my original question

Answer (score 0):

This one has been tested, I've spent some time on it, please let me know if you're happy with the result and vote if yes, cheers :-)  PS: The table dbo.Months_and_Years contains your data (with the 2 missing months)

```
            CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Table  ( 
            [Year] SMALLINT,
            [Month] TINYINT
            );

            INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Table
            VALUES 
            (2014, 1),
            (2014, 2),
            (2014, 3),
            (2014, 4),
            (2014, 5),
            (2014, 6),
            (2014, 7),
            (2014, 9),
            (2014, 10),
            (2014, 12);




            DECLARE @MinValue TINYINT = 1
            DECLARE @MaxValue TINYINT = 100

            WHILE @MinValue < = @MaxValue

            BEGIN
            DECLARE @Missing_Month TINYINT = (

                        SELECT TOP 1 A.RowID
                        FROM (
                        SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY [month])  AS RowID ,
                         *
                        FROM dbo.Test_Table
                        ) AS A
                        WHERE A.RowID <> A.[Month]
                        )
            SELECT  @Missing_Month

            IF @Missing_Month IS NULL

            BREAK

            ELSE
            INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Table
            VALUES (2014, @Missing_Month)

            SET @MinValue = @MinValue + 1

            END


            -- Check your results ---
            SELECT A.*
            FROM dbo.Test_Table AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.Months_and_Years AS B  ON A.[Month] = B.[Month]
            WHERE B.[Month] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Claudio. the example can be b/w two different calendar years(I added a note to my question) ie 2013 mm - 2014 mm